# ElasTICSEARCH resource_already_exists_exception IN Magento 2 WHILE REindexing

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, magento2

ElasticSuite Category Indexing index process unknown error given as shown below:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [missi_default_catalog_category_missiindices/Cv5ewK3dSLKzecqC5k6Z6g] already exists","index_uuid":"Cv5ewK3dSLKzecqC5k6Z6g","index":"missi_default_catalog_category_missiindices"}],"type":"resource_already_exists_exception","reason":"index [missi_default_catalog_category_missiindices/Cv5ewK3dSLKzecqC5k6Z6g] already exists","index_uuid":"Cv5ewK3dSLKzecqC5k6Z6g","index":"missi_default_catalog_category_missiindices"},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento added support for Elasticsearch 5+ in 2.2.2 or 2.2.3 (before that only 2.x was supported), and to use that you need to set the Search Engine setting to Elasticsearch 5.0+ in admin, or

- `magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch5_server_hostname elasticsearch` 
  (where `elasticsearch` your ElasticSearch server hostname)
- `magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch5`

in CLI.

Comment: Magento 2.4,2 has been Elasticsearch connection tested successful but the issue  is not come when  re  indexing its  first time with no error but now then it showing error in while indexing the index elasticsuite_categories_full please suggest the solution.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: if you do not change the search engine setting in Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search then the catalog_product index will not be generated in ElasticSearch.